# E: Unable to find a source package for 'r-base' on Ubuntu 16.04 (aarch64)

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, r

I want to `sudo apt build-dep r-base` under Ubuntu 16.04 (running in Linux on DeX Beta). To this end, I followed [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) and put

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-backports main restricted universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-backports main restricted universe
```

into `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then did

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

and then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt build-dep r-base
```

... but obtain:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for r-base
```

I've done these things before and recently under Ubuntu 19.04 (guess that's not relevant), is the `aarch64` architecture a possible problem here? (I could install all sorts of preliminaries to build R from source (Tcl/Tk, GSL, GMP, MPFR...), all no problem). Let me know if you need the output of certain commands.

Note:

Concerning `/etc/apt/sources.list`: There was already a line `deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial main restricted` and I also commented in the same line starting with `deb-src` instead of `deb`. This led to exactly the same output. The file also contains the lines `deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial universe`.

Comment: I just added a note. I tried to also explicitly use `deb-src... `, did not work either, same outcome.

Comment: If I add `universe` after `restricted` I get a lot of warnings of the form `W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list`. Ah, right, because the line with `universe` is actually there... AHHHH... I see now... the `universe` line was only there for `deb`, not `deb-src`... Great, it works! Never had to use that explicitly.